# Can I add params values to a hash?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User model.  I also have a form_for(@user...) form.  This form spans 3 partials.  In order for every partial to remember values I use the following command inside my create action in my UsersController:

```
session[:user_params].deep_merge!(params[:user]) if params[:user]
```

This way every partial adds params[:user] to session[:user_params].  I also have other form values stored inside the params hash which are not part of the User model.  Is there a command which would allow me to add all single params values (not just the :user hash) to the session[:user_params] hash without adding every single value one by one like this:

```
session[:num_children] = params[:num_children] if params[:num_children]
...etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
params.each {|key,value| session.deep_merge!(key=>value)}
```